# Printing a list of plotly plots with title and subtitle in rmd

Tags: r, loops, plotly, r-markdown

I have a function that I am using to generate a list of plotly plots and text for a title and subtitle. I would like to loop through this list to print the plots in my .rmd file. Here is the code I have:

```
plot_outputs <- my_function_to_make_lists(input1, input2)

plot_list <- plot_outputs
    plot_outputs <- lapply(names(plot_list), function(plot_name) {
      print(tagList(
        p(tags$strong(plot_list[[plot_name]]$table_text), plot_list[[plot_name]]$title, class = "subtitle"),  
        p(tags$em(plot_list[[plot_name]]$subtitle, class = "subtitle")),
        plot_list[[plot_name]]$plot,
        p(style = "margin-bottom: 75px;"),
      ))
    })
```

This prints the title and subtitle fine in my knitted document, but the plots are not printing.

The function is working to generate the plots fine and the plot prints when I run:

```
plot_list[[1]]$plot
```

However when I try to print the list it is not working. Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated. To note I have very similar code for a list of reactables and titles/subtitles, and that is printing in the knitted rmd.

Thank you!

Comment: what are you chunk options in this case?

Comment: `{r plots, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE}`
I have actually fixed this issue now through some more research!
`plot_list <- plot_outputs
l <- htmltools::tagList()
for(i in 1:length(plot_list)){
  l[[i]] <- tagList(
    p(tags$strong(plot_list[[i]]$plot_text), plot_list[[i]]$title, class = "subtitle"), 
        p(tags$em(plot_list[[i]]$subtitle, class = "subtitle")),
        plot_list[[i]]$plot,
        p(style = "margin-bottom: 75px;")
  )
}`